# Why is mouseout and mouseleave always firing

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mouseout

I really don't get why the `p` element is always hidden (and therefore why the `mouseout` is always firing):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const infoBox = document.querySelector("#info-box")
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", evt => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    infoBox.style.display="block"
    infoBox.style.position="absolute"
    infoBox.style.top= evt.clientY+"px"
    infoBox.style.left=evt.clientX+"px"
    console.log("moved")
})
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", evt => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    infoBox.style.display="none"
    console.log("exit")
}, false)
```

```css
canvas{
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color:#212121;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="info-box" style="display: none;"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

Comment: The exit happens every time the `info-box` appears. It's likely due to that. Try using an offset away from the mouse? `evt.clientY+ 2 + "px"` for example

Comment: @evolutionxbox how can i donate like 5k points to you? ahaha

Comment: @evolutionxbox sure leave an answer, i'll accept it immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit happens every time the info-box appears.
Adding an offset to the `#info-box` div means that the mouse doesn't think it has left the canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const infoBox = document.querySelector("#info-box");
const mouseOffset = 2;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  infoBox.style.display = "block"
  infoBox.style.position = "absolute"
  infoBox.style.top = evt.clientY + mouseOffset + "px" // add an offset here
  infoBox.style.left = evt.clientX + mouseOffset + "px" // and here
  console.log("moved")
})
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  infoBox.style.display = "none"
  console.log("exit")
}, false)
```

```css
canvas {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: #212121;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="info-box" style="display: none;">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```